# Get latest revision vid in views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm using the revisioning module to handle the status of nodes. As far as the nodes go, they've been working perfect and the work flow is exactly what I want. However, I'm running into an issue when trying to construct a view.

What I'm able to do so far:

- Create the view
- Set the node type
- Limit it to only nodes that have pending revisions

  - (I get the two nodes with pending revisions (an unpublished rev)
- Get the nid of the node

Where I'm having issues:

- I try to select the vid of the pending revision, but instead I get the vid of the currently published revision.

I'm not sure where to go. I've tried using "Type: Content" and "Type: Content revision" and get the exact same behavior. I've tried playing with Relationships and still get the same behavior, but I don't think a relationship touches what I need.

... This is incredibly irritating because I'm obviously getting the pending nodes that I want, I'm just not getting the vid for what's pending (which is what my filter uses to get those nodes in the first place) and instead getting it for what's published.

I can imagine there might be some headache because it's possible to have multiple pending revisions, in that case, I should see two lines for that one nid since nid and vid /should/ be unique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I needed doesn't exist. I had to write something with views_php to get what I needed. What worked was heavily influenced by https://drupal.org/node/1081804.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of views_php use something like this. Add it as a field - you just need a custom handler to call the revisioning function that returns the latest vid.

```
/*
* Implements hook_views_data_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['node_revision']['latest_revision'] = array(
    'title' => t('Latest revision'),
    'help' => t('Get the latest vid.'),
    'group' => t('Content revision'),
    'real field' => 'nid',
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'MYMODULE_field_handler_latest_revision',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
  );
}
```

And the handler:

```
/**
 * Provide the latest revision number from the nid field.
 */
class MYMODULE_field_handler_latest_revision extends views_handler_field {

  // Return latest vid as the field value.
  public function render($values) {
    $value = $this->get_value($values);
    return revisioning_get_latest_revision_id($value);
  }
}
```